# Teaching linear algebra, wacom tablet display of coordinate system, eigenvectors, markov chains

Tags: linear-algebra, online-instruction, software, vectors

I am teaching linear algebra as part of an information retrieval course, which now occurs online. I have a Wacom tablet and free drawing software, sketchBook for artists, so can draw circles ellipses etc. I need better software to draw cartesian coordinate systems, which includes grids and is preferably aimed at teaching mathematics. Can you advise whether there is such a package out there? An internet search has not brought one up. I know and use Mathematica, but it may be a little overkill to go that route. Perhaps a combination of Wacom and Mathematica would work. If you have examples of your own teaching of linear algebra (e.g. eigenvalues, eigenvectors, similar matrices, spectral decomposition etc) I'd much appreciate tips on how to set it up best.

Comment: I don't know about wacom tablets specifically, but one thing that I have found useful is to draw (by hand, Mathematica or tikz) any complicated figures I expect to use in advance and then copy paste them into my digital whiteboard.

Comment: The technique I've used to draw a quick grid is to draw a vertical line, copy it to right with the desired width. Then copy the two lines as a pair, lining the left copy up with the right so that the width matches. Then copy the '3' lines (one is a double line) so that the new left and right match and you get 5. One more time gets you 9. Now do the same with horizontal lines. It's pretty quick to do and has a nice hand drawn feel. (as opposed to an exact generated feel)

Comment: [xournalpp](https://github.com/xournalpp/xournalpp) has some grid backgrounds, but its "coordinate system" drawing option just produces an L-shape as far as I can see.